# How to get the isolated storage path for accessing the files and folders in windows phone7 application?

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

In windows mobile 6 applications, I use code like `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)`
to get the application path.

Likewise in windows phone7 application, how to get the isolated storage path and how to access the files and folders in my application?
Please give me a sample code for develop my application.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()` to get an object which can manipulate files and directories in Isolated Storage.

See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) which has plenty of example code.

Comment: you are right, he can use like "var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()" also this is the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

have a look here: [Retrieving file path from IsolatedStorage](http://msmvps.com/blogs/angelhernandez/archive/2008/10/04/retrieving-file-path-from-isolatedstorage.aspx)

```
isoStore.GetType.GetField("m_RootDir", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(isoStore).ToString();
                                       ^ or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
```